# Access file from another maven module

Tags: java, maven

How to write 2 poms:

- one for a master module which holds some configuration (*.properties) files refered in spring configuration
- and another for a 'slave' module that include some spring components and needs/uses these configuration files (to proper configure themselves)
  Thank you

Comment: I can imagine you can use `src\main\resources` in the parent module for your property files.

Comment: I would rather use Spring resource capabilities to access these files using _classpath:_, so that just adding the dependency on the master module is needed.

Comment: yes and how do you add those dependencies exactly?